# Pyinstaller and hiddenimports: how to force to import a package that doesn't get automatically imported by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to **generate a .exe file using pyinstaller**.

It works fine, except for fact that **one package was not automatically detected and imported by pyinstaller**.

Such package, that in this example we will call "**packageOfInterest**", did not get imported because the **developers did not provide an hook**.

Reading some documentation I understood that **this issue could be easily fixed with the following line to be added in the .spec**:

```
hiddenimports=["packageOfInterest"]
```

Unfortunately **it doesn't work**, the **"packageOfInterest" was not imported** even using such line of code.

**So my question is: What I'm still missing in the .spec file?**

Below my **.spec file** that I've been using **with success with many applications where the packages could be automatically detected by pyinstaller**, therefore **this is not the case**.

```
import sys
import os

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
path = os.path.abspath(".")

a = Analysis(
    ["MyScript.py"],

    # "packageOfInterest" in the "hiddenimports" is the package name
    #  that pyinstaller could not import automatically
    hiddenimports=["kivymd.stiffscroll", "packageOfInterest"],

    pathex=[path],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    datas = [("media\\", "media\\")],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=None,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=None)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name="MyScript",
    console=True,
    icon='myicon.ico'
)
```

The location of "packageOfInterest" is at the path:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages
```

**Maybe this path should be specified somewhere** (e.g. should be addedd in the "pathex" after the "path" value).

In general would be **great to identify a clear method** that **check for all packages imported via "MyScript.py" that cannot automatically be imported by pyinstaller**, **and that will force their import**.

At the same time would be appreciated to **understand how to customized to .spec in order to fix the issue**.

thanks in advance

Comment: What error message __do you get__ that shows you the module hasn't been imported - show the full traceback in your question? Have __you checked__ the messages during running of pyinstaller to see if there are __any messages__ about your __hidden import__?

Comment: What exactly is __packagofinterest__? Have you tried asking __its developers__ about __how to use it__ with pyinstaller?

Comment: __You might want__ to check these tips for diagnosing __when things go wrong__ using pyinstaller https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly

Comment: The .exe crashed because one file is not showing. Such file was belonging to the "packageofinterest" (mne). I contacted MNE developers without success. Looking at the C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI61962 (where the files of the .exe get temporarily placed) all the folders related to the packages using a hook are present, while the folder of MNE is missing. If I manually copy the package folder of MNE inside the root, everything works fine, but this is not a clean way to operate. I would expect that hiddenimports=["mne"] could solve the issue, but as already said, it doesn't work.

Comment: However this issue is not related only to mne. I did the same with another package (joblib), that was not automatically imported by pyinstaller and the result was the same: the hiddenimport  of joblib did not help to import its package folder. joblib folder is missing inside the root.
That's why I'm sure that SOMETHING IS MISSING IN THE .SPEC. Someone has some more tips? thanks

Comment: Did you try applying all the tips in that __link i posted__ in comment above? E.g _not_ using onefile but using onedir instead, … and all the others.

Comment: I found if I added the missing package to the hiddenimports option, it would copy the model but it was still missing unless I manually copied also the corresponding `.dist-info` folder. E.g.  `tqdm-4.64.1.dist-info`

Answer (score 0):

```
The .exe crashed because one file is not showing. Such file was belonging to the "packageofinterest" (mne)
```

hmm.. you could try use `--collect-data packageofinterest` as it seems you are missing some files which are belongs to the package.

Also you can use `--hidden-import packageofinterest` if you don't want to use the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems old but I hope it helps someone in the future. I recently tried to create a GUI Bundling app. that circumvents as many imported module related issues when I encountered similar interest of forcing PyInstaller to pickup module used by any project I try to Bundle into executable. Here's my workaround.

Every Python module has the ****file**** and/or ****path**** property/ies. This is because every third-party implementation we install for use (via pip, easy_install, etc) is provided as a module(path via **file**) or a package(path via **path**). Only those available as a package have access to both ****file**** and ****path**** properties.

So, let's assume the modules that couldn't be picked up by PyInstaller are **zipfile** and **psutil**. The former is a module while the later is a package.

```
import zipfile  # Use any of the import rules.
print( zipfile.__file__ )  # Take a look at where its absolute path resides.

import psutil
print( psutil.__path__ )
print( psutil.__file__ )  # This will return the package's __init__.py file. Definitely not what you want.
```

Now, add this path to your PyInstaller's command using the **--add-data** option.
**syntax**:

```
pyinstaller --add-data module_absolute_path;destination my_program_startup_file.py
```

NOTE:
-The spaces around the **print** statements is only for readability sake.
-The **destination** is always a '.' for modules and module name for packages Ex: **psutil/** [refer PyInstaller documentation for clarity]

**Example**:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --clean --add-data C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\psutil;psutil\ my_program_startup_file.py
```